# Kubuntu 12.04 looks very bad on IBM T23

Tags: 12.04, graphics, kubuntu, icons, desktop-environments

I'm using a Linux OS for the first time (Kubuntu 12.04) and I'm absolutely amazed of it. I learned a lot in the past few days, and everything works great on my old machine but the looks of the OS is absolutely unacceptable.

I couldn't figure it out by my self so I decided to ask for help in this forum.

But see it yourself:

[image]

[image]

Would like it to just look clean and simple.

I really hope, that someone can help me here, because besides this, everything works just fine on my beloved T23. I also don't need no glowing buttons and things like this, but first things first.

Comment: What is the graphics card in this system? It's also wise to know Kubuntu 12.04 is a rather heavy OS for such an old computer. I would advise you to try out a lightweight Linux distribution like Xubuntu instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give some suggestions that may fix your problem, but it's not very likely. The problem probably is in the graphics card (have you installed the proper drivers?).

Please remember the original settings before changing anything. If one suggestion doesn't work, revert the changes and try another one.

- Go to **Desktop Effects – KDE Control Module** → **Advanced** and try changing the following settings:

  - **Compositing type**
  - **Qt graphics system**
  - **Use OpenGL 2 Shaders**
  - **Use VSync**

  (Don't forget to press **Apply**).

  Also go to the **General** tab and press the key combination that is shown there.
- Go to **Style – KDE Control Module** → **Applications** and select a different **Widget style**.

  Go to the **Fine Tuning** tab and change the **Graphical Effects** setting to **Low display resolution and Low CPU**